# Can you change the default output from SLURM's squeue command?

Tags: default, slurm

The default output from SLURM is:
JOBID PARTITION     NAME     USER ST       TIME  NODES NODELIST(REASON)

I'd like it have the QOS too:
JOBID PARTITION     NAME     USER ST       TIME  NODES NODELIST(REASON) QOS

Is there a way to change the default so I don't have to specify the option every time?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You simply set the `SQUEUE_FORMAT` environment variable with the options you specify on the command line.

Exemple:

```
export SQUEUE_FORMAT="%.18i %.9P %.8j %.8u %.2t %.10M %.6D %.20R %q"
```

Write the above line in your `.bash_profile` file and you will always have the additional QOS column in your output.